# The difference between .click() & .on()

Tags: jquery

i wanna know , What is the difference between

```
$('.element').click(function() { 
     //code 
});
```

and

```
$('.element').on('click' , function() {
     //code 
});
```

Tnx for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$('html').on('click', '.element', function() {
 //code to run on click
});
```

This makes a real difference.

So, if you add new `.element` elements dynamically (via ajax or js) they will have the `click` event associated.

If you use just

```
$('.element').click(function() { 
     //code 
});
```

and then you add new `.element` elements they will not have any function associated to the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) is your friend.

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements

https://api.jquery.com/on/

> Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

https://api.jquery.com/click/